# How can I use csv module to replace empty value in column with the value from the row above it?

Tags: python, csv, replace

I am working with the CSV module in python and I am trying to trying to fill in blank values in one specific column with the value from the previous row
I can do this in excel but I want to run this program on a cronjob so i'm trying to figure out how to do it in python

for example

{{AAA, BBB, CCC} , {DDD,    , EEE} , {FFF, GGG, HHH} , {III,    , JJJ} , {KKK,    all, LLL}, {MMM, NNN, OOO}}

should become

{{AAA, BBB, CCC} , {DDD, BBB, EEE} , {FFF, GGG, HHH} , {III, GGG, JJJ} , {KKK, GGG, LLL}, {MMM, NNN, OOO}}

thanks for any help or suggestions

Comment: If the same column has a blank value in multiple lines in a row, should the same value from the last row that had something non-blank be used for them all? That is, should `[[a, b], [c, ], [d, ]]` get the `b` repeated in both of the succeeding rows, or just the one that starts with `c`? Is the first row always going to have values for all columns?

Comment: in this form I would want [[a,b], [c,b], [d,b]], the goal is to get them all to fill until a new value appears, then have all blanks after that filled with the new value etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by saving the previous row in a variable, and using its values to replace any strings that are empty in the succeeding row:

```
with open(in_filename, newline="") as f_in, open(out_filename, "w", newline="") as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)    # setup code
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)

    row = next(reader)           # handle first line (with no replacements)
    writer.writerow(row)
    last_row = row               # always save the last row of data that we've written

    for row in reader:           # loop over the rest of the lines
        row = [x if x else y for x, y in zip(row, last_row)]  # replace empty strings
        writer.writerow(row)
        last_row = row
```

This code assumes that you want to keep using the same previous value if there are blank items in several successive rows in the same column (not only replace the first). If there are blank values in the first row, they will not be replaced.

I'm also using one of Python 3 new parameters to `open` to get `csv` module compatible file objects. If you're using Python 2 you'll need to open the files a bit differently. If that is that case, open both files in binary mode (modes `"rb"` and `"wb"`) and get rid of the `newline` keyword parameters.

You may also need to pass in parameters `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` to describe your specific CSV dialect (e.g. delimiter, quote style, etc.) if the defaults don't work for your file.